Where can I find good examples of hydrophone recordings of whales that I can compare my recordings to?
Where can I find high quality hydrophone recordings of whales to study and compare my hydrophone recordings with? Lots of noisy poorly recorded examples online and lots of whale song with mixed in music on YouTube. Looking for high quality Humpback whale vocalizations. Thank you for your help with this.

Also, see the answers provided in this question on Bioacoustics Stack Exchange

DOSITS has an audio gallery and there are several examples of humpback whale vocalizations there. You can also do a literature search for your specific region and see what has been published on humpbacks in your study area.
